# Reload partial view using AJAX with Json response in Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

When I call $.getJSON, i want to reload tbody elements. In other words, I need to delete all elements and put new elements by Json response.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#position').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
         $.getJSON('/save_positions.json', {ids:newOrder}, function(data){
            ??????
         });
    }
  });
});
```

My View

```
# index.html.erb

<tbody id="position">
  <%= render :partial => "activities"%>
</tbody>
```

Partial View

```
#_activities.html.erb

<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <tr id='<%= activity.id %>'>
    <td><%= activity.position %></td>
    <td><%= link_to activity.id, activity_path(activity) %></td>
    <td><%= activity.name %></td>
    <td><%= activity.estimated %></td>
    <td><%= activity.used %></td>
    <td><%=l activity.created_at %></td>
  </tr>
```

My Action (Application Controller)

```
def save_positions
  @activities = Activity.all(:order => 'position')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @activities }
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to generate the new HTML on the server, return that, and insert it into the document, OR do you want to return JSON and process that in the JavaScript to generate new HTML?

Comment: Whatever.. I only want to reload table without reload page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I get the impression that what you're trying to do is generate new HTML server-side and insert it into the document. If that's the case, try something like this:

```
$.get( '/save_positions', { ids : newOrder } ).done( function( data ) {

  $( "#position" ).html( $( data ).html() );

} );
```

If you really want to return JSON, then you'll probably want to return an array of objects and iterate over it to generate new HTML, perhaps using a templating engine like Mustache, e.g.:

No template engine:

```
$.getJSON( '/save_positions.json', { ids : newOrder } ).done( function( data ) {

  var positions = [];

  $.each( data, function ( key, val ) {

    // generate an element
    var el = $( "<tr>" );

    // ...

    positions.push( el );

  } );

  $( "#position" ).empty().append( positions );

} );
```

or

JS:

```
$.getJSON( '/save_positions.json', { ids : newOrder } ).done( function( data ) {

  var positions = Mustache.render( template, data );

  $( "#position" ).html( positions );

} );
```

Mustache template:

```
{{#positions}}

<tr id='{{activity.id}}'>
  <td>{{activity.position}}</td>
  <td>{{activity.url}}</td>
  <td>{{activity.name}}</td>
  <td>{{activity.estimated}}</td>
  <td>{{activity.used}}</td>
  <td>{{activity.created_at}}</td>
</tr>

{{/positions}}
```

Comment: I want to generate new html using _activities.html.erb.. This command is cleaning the table elements, but is not filling with Json response.. I can do without using Mustache?

Comment: If you're generating the HTML on the server, then you can just send an HTML resonse, you don't need JSON. Try my first snippet of code that uses `$.get( '/save_positions' ...`, instead of the `$.getJSON('/save_positions.json' ...` in your code. Use Chrome developer tools / Firebug / something to see exactly what is in the response and make sure it's the HTML you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks JMM!!!!! I used the first option (HTML server-side).. but I changed `'$( "#position" ).html( $( data ).html() );'` by `'$( "#position" ).html( data);'`

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure exactly what HTML you're returning -- are you sure that's not giving you a `tbody` within `tbody`, e.g. `<tbody><tbody><tr>...`? (You can inspect it with Chrome dev tools or Firebug.)

Comment: Its returning only `<tr><td></td></tr>...` without <tbody>

Comment: Ok, cool. (SO really really wants me to type some extra chars here...)